# tensorflow tf.initializeallvariables() taking too much time even while init with few variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow is taking too much time to run the tf.initializeallvariables() routine for some reason. I am using cuda 8.0 with NVIDIA TitanX Pascal and latest tensorflow. I am not sure about the reason and would appreciate any help.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

cls = np.zeros((5, 10))
classes = tf.Variable(cls, dtype=tf.float32)

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

Comment: How long is it taking?

Comment: It is taking 80s for a bunch of more variables. The time is not much but I was curious that it is taking this much even for few variables. Also I didn't see this much delay on another machine that I was working on.

Comment: It's possible that it's spending a lot of time copying data (although 80s sounds excessive) or running random number generators (depending on how you initialize the variables). The best bet is to [collect a timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3850/measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations/13324/basic-example-with-tensorflows-timeline-object#t=20161123010716931335) when you run `tf.initialize_all_variables()` and it should tell you what ops are taking a long time.

Comment: Thanks mrry, will do that to find out.

Comment: One other note: initializing variables from NumPy arrays is usually slower than initializing them from the equivalent TensorFlow op (e.g. `tf.zeros((5, 10))` in this case) because this will materialize the whole NumPy array in the TensorFlow `GraphDef` and make multiple copies of the constant data. If you use the TensorFlow op, the value will be created on demand when you run the initializer, and discarded afterwards.